# Javascript implementation of Blowfish ECB Encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

[Transferred from [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/javascript-implementation-of-blowfish-ecb-encryption)]

I'm looking for a javascript library that supports ECB Blowfish encryption/decryption with a symmetric key. Do any exist?

I've seen some in a Google search but they their either don't support Blowfish or don't support ECB.

I know that ECB is insecure, I don't really care about that so please don't comment that, I'm mostly just trying to decode information that is already encrypted with it and/or communicate with an API that requires it.

Answer (score 2):

I think Dojo framework supports Blowfish in ECB mode. Well check this code (Scroll down a little bit) : [Blowfish-ECB mode](http://www.bedework.org/trac/bedework/browser/trunk/deployment/resources/javascript/dojo-0.4.1-ajax/src/crypto/Blowfish.js?rev=1164)